# Decimal separator issue from SAP to Excel: "1,056" versus "1.056" (factor 1000)

Tags: vba, numbers, excel-2010, sap-erp, cell-formatting

I have written a VBA code in excel which is linked with SAP and it downloads the table VBRP in an excel sheet.

I have a problem with numbers. For example the billed quantity is 1.056 in SAP, when macro runs and trying to paste the value in excel then we have the number 1,056 not the one thousand and 56.

When I load the table by VBA and the copy paste manual the table in excel using Ctrl + V then I have the correct number 1.056 one thousand and 56 items.

What should I do in order to have the correct numbers in my excel?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will edit my post during the day.

Answer (score 0):

you could remove the dots before inserting to the sheet. The number format set on your column will than be applied independent of the regional settings of the used machine. Something like this:

```
Sub testdecimalsep()
    Dim test
    test = Split("1.11, 1.00001, 5.333", ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(test)
        test(i) = CLng(Replace(test(i), ".", ""))
    Next i

    Sheet1.Range("A1:A3").Value2 = Application.Transpose(test)
End Sub
```

best of luck,